# Double buffering in delphi

Tags: delphi

Using Delphi XE2 I wanted to make some buttons move in delphi application.

I wrote this code:

```
procedure TForm1.DoSomething;
var x : integer;
begin    
   for x := 200 downto 139 do begin
       // move two buttons
      Button1.Top := x;
      Button3.Top := x;
       // skip some repaints to reduce flickering
      if (x mod 7 = 1) then begin
          Form1.Repaint;
      Sleep(50);
   end;
end;
```

Unfortunately it still significantly flickers when running this procedure.

Here's my question:
Is there any way, to make the animation smooth (without any flickering)?

**Edit:**
To make animation more smooth, change 50 to something smaller in sleep(50) and delete this line:

```
if(x mod 7 = 1) then begin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `Form1.DoubleBuffered` to `True`. You can do this in code, but I think the property is published in XE2, so you can set it in the Object Inspector as well.

Comment: Such a powerful property. Thanks, I will tick as accepted after 10 minutes

Comment: Yes, but a property that is liable to lead to nasty visual quirks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is absolutely spot on, if you can find a way of repainting flickerless without the use of double buffering then try and do that. from my own experience, and as David pointed out double buffering often leads to some visual problems like dark edges around buttons etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that it is better to decide how long you want the movement to take instead of using the Sleep procedure.  This adjusts better for different speed computers and will also adjust for different distances being moved.  If you want it to take 1 second to move across the screen you need to move by smaller steps between repaints vs. only taking .5 seconds to move across the screen.

I don't remember exactly why but we also added code to repaint the parent.  I think we were having problems with a ghost image being left as our object moved across the screen.

Here is the code we are using.  This is inside a component that can shift itself on and off the screen.

```
procedure TMyObject.ShiftRight;
var
  TicksStart: int64;
  StartLeftValue: integer;
  EndLeftValue: integer;
  NewLeftValue: integer;
  LeftValueDif: integer;
  RemainingTicks: int64;

begin
  StartLeftValue := Self.Left;
  EndLeftValue := Self.Left + Self.Width;
  LeftValueDif := EndLeftValue - StartLeftValue;

  TicksStart := GetTickCount();
  RemainingTicks := FadeTime;  // Fade Time is a constants that dermines how long the 
                               // slide off the screen should take

  while RemainingTicks > 0 do
  begin
    NewLeftValue := (LeftValueDif * (FadeTime - RemainingTicks)) div FadeTime;
    Self.Left := Max(StartLeftValue, NewLeftValue);
    Self.Parent.Repaint;
    Self.Repaint;

    RemainingTicks := FadeTime - int64(GetTickCount - TicksStart);
  end;

  if Self.Left < EndLeftValue then
    Self.Left := EndLeftValue;

  Self.Parent.Repaint;    
  Self.Repaint;
end;
```

Comment: I have also noticed that sleep makes application on different computers work randomly. Anyway, thanks for feedback.

Comment: This is indeed a common approach: calculate where the object should be in the current point in time. I also do wonder about the two repaints, though. Actually, I think I would choose not to do this in a loop like this, because it will block the application while the loop runs. Instead, I think I'd use a timer, put the inners of the loop into its OnTimer event, and use Self.Invalidate to request the repaint. It will allow fast users to continue working immediately without having to wait for the animation to complete.